# Visualization of clusters created using DBSCAN

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, visualization

I am clustering the geographical data points using DBSCAN clustering algorithm. For 500K+ points, I get 900 clusters.

Code used for clustering:

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=13/6371., min_samples=20, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(coords))

cluster_labels = db.labels_

se = pd.Series(cluster_labels)

df3['Cluster'] = se.values
```

Sample output:

```
Latitude    Longitude   Cluster
48.462       -68.3214   761
32.111       -111.311   123
```

Now I am trying to plot the lat-long pairs along with its cluster circle on a map. I tried using folium, but I was not able to plot the cluster circle.

I referred to this blog http://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/, but in finding the cluster center point, I was not able to import the libray MultiPoint.

Just wondering is there any way to plot the clusters along with its associated data points on a map.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a ton !!

Comment: Don't use that blog post: There are some really *bad decisions* there, and data set reduction is not what DBSCAN is suited for. DBSCAN clusters are not circles, they can be any shape and size! The blog should have used Leader clustering instead.